# Is Canvas overkill for a business application?

Tags: html

I'm building a business application which mostly involves tables and other typical form elements.  Due to the nature of my application however,  I need to place groups of these elements together in a dynamic tree structure which will take up all of the available screen real estate.  If real estate is low, there will be some form of smart scrolling allowing users to focus on certain areas of the tree.   It could be called an advanced data visualization web form.

Historically, I would have accomplished this by simply using divs and javascript.  The canvas element however seems like a more logical way to build my structure.  Most uses of the canvas element that I can find are however geared towards graphics and animations (mostly games).   Is canvas overkill for this?  Will I benefit from using it?  Are there alternatives?

[image]

Comment: I think it depends on your application. DOM is normally faster since browsers are optimized to render DOM as fast as possible. And DOM looks more authentic than a canvas images due to browser differences. You may also think about non-javascript users and those who use browsers that don't support canvas.

Comment: There's simply no way I'm accomplishing what I want without javascript.  The UI will be very dynamic and postbacks aren't acceptable.

Comment: I have.  Why would it be more appropriate than canvas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, canvas is overkill. It is very much a drawing board and not much more. It is certainly not something that I would expect to create user controls in. Games etc. are more suited as they aren't really standard user controls and wouldn't be expected to behave as such.

A tree structure could easily be implemented with a series of nested `ul`s. Using some JavaScript to expand collapse them by adding and removing classes.

[Here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/) is a nice jQuery plugin for you to use or get some ideas of how you could use it.

Edit:
I would stay away from canvas just because of the overhead of the drawing. If you can extend a standard JavaScript treeview to add more functionality this would seem like the best option ot me. Creating controls from scratch in canvas is no small feat.

Edit2 (Post mockup):
This just looks like a multi-part form to me, with hidden forms/areas which are displayed as apropriately. This is far too common to require creating this with canvas.

Comment: No, the "nodes" of my tree will be much more complex than text and images.   A tree is only one way of looking at it.  A dynamic grid layout with changing widths and number of rows and columns could also describe what I'm building.

Comment: @Mr Grieves - A mockup or further explanation may be required to determine the suitability.

Answer (score -1):

Canvas is not fully supported in all browsers yet.  I recommend using either Jquery or another framework.